# MVC3 Empty model on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, model

I have model which has data.
The i create form with only on button, i don't use the model's data in there. 
When i press the button it goes correctly to the HTTPPOST method but the model is completely empty.

**HTML:**

```
@model ViewModels.RequestDeletionViewObject
@using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  }
```

**The RequestDeletionViewObject:**

```
public class RequestDeletionViewObject : ViewModelBase 
    { 
        public TreeGridData NodeFilespacesData { get; set; } 
        public Dictionary<long, string> EmailList{ get; set; } 
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult RequestDel() 
        { 

            return View(_businessLogic.GetData()); 

        } 

        [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult RequestDel(RequestDeletionViewObject model)  
        { 
            return View(_businessLogic.GetData());  
        }
```

Please help me, I have done similar thing in many other places and it worked there, but not here, i don't know what am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but dont you need to pass the values in the view to keep it "alive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any form controls in your form.  A form will only post data that is in a form control (textbox, hidden field, checkbox, etc..)

It doesn't matter what data you send to the view, it will only post back data in form controls within the form.

Comment: Yep MM is correct, tie up a control to the NodeFilespacesData or the EmailList so that the form has data or just test it by adding a property like public string TestString { get; set; } to your model and then add @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestString) to your view

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! It worked exactly as you suggested :)